# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim sqlstr As String = ("insert into users (username, password) values('bb','ss')")
 comand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
 If con.State() Then con.Close()
    con.Open()
    comand.Connection = con
    comand.ExecuteNonQuery()
 End If
```

Comment: maybe users is a reserved keyword?

Comment: Also: don't store passwords in plaintext. And don't treat State() like a boolean, It's an Enum.

Comment: You do not mention the whole error message, which should give a clue, but `password` is a reserved keyword. If this is MSSQL, use `insert into [users] ([username], [password]) values('bb','ss')`

Comment: http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` is a keyword. Depending on the db `Users` might be, so try:

```
Dim sqlstr As String = ("insert into [dbo].[users] (username, password) values('bb','ss')")
comand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
If con.State() Then con.Close()
  con.Open()
  comand.Connection = con
  comand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If
```

Also do not store the UN/PW as plain text.